# i have a error in andriod studio but i dont know what is the probleme

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk, manifest

The `targetSdk` version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the `defaultConfig` in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion need to be removed from the manifest file and set to the build.gradle file. I believe, Android Studio is providing an option to fix the issue automatically.

If you choose it, android studio automatically update the following files to define minSdk and targetSdk values in Gradle instead of AndroidManifest.xml:

1. /app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
2. /app/build.gradle

You can do it manually be removing the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion from the manifest and update it at the build.gradle file.

Example /app/build.gradle file
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hardian.sample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```